# How to jump to dial pad in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

To make a phone call, use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"tel://"]` it's very easy.

The problem is: I don't want to dial immediately, I need when user taps the 'call' button, app jumps to dial pad in phone app, and displays specific phone number, user can press 'Call' button to make this phone call.
Anybody know how can I achieve this?
Appreciate!

Comment: As a side note: Don't forget to first check for `[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url`.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone SDK not allows you to dial a number from the application. But you can do it by using a `UITextField`. Set keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad`

```
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
```

and set that number to `textfield`,

```
textfield.text = numberToDial;
```

and then call the following line when user taps on your call button

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",textfield.text]]];
```